# weird typecasting ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();

Tags: java

I am learning java and spring on the way, I have the following code for which I do not understand how typecasting works:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/voja/spring/test/beans/beans.xml");

        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();

    }

}
```

So the following:

```
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
```

is what I don't get.

My thinking is that it should be like:

```
(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context.close();
```

But that gives an error.

The way it is now it's how it's supposed to be, but I don't get how is the method invoked on it, and why is `(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context` inside brackets, and once again how can a method be appended to this?

Comment: `context` in this area is actually an `ApplicationContext`, so when you say `context.close();` without casting, you get an error. If you do as you said and cast it without enclosing in parenthesis such as `(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context.close();`, you are casting the result of `context.close()` to the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. Instead, you want to cast just the `context` object to the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, hence why it is enclosed in parenthesis at `((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();`

Comment: I don't understand what the confusion here is. Expressions in parenthese are evaluated first, so this code casts first and then calls `close` on the casted object. The other code tries to call `close` first and then casts the result. Its not different than simple math like `(1 + 2) * 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context`'s compile type type is `ApplicationContext`. Assuming the run-time type of `context` is `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, in order to call methods of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, you must cast `context` to `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.

```
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
```

is a shorter way of writing :

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cpcontext = (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context;
cpcontext.close();
```

without the parentheses, the compiler checks whether the compile time type of `context` (i.e. `ApplicationContext`) has a `close()` method. If it doesn't, the code doesn't pass compilation.

with the parentheses, the compiler checks whether `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` has a `close()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is: the expression "works" from right to left.

So, when you have

```
Foo foo = ...
(X) foo.bar();
```

the compiler assumes that foo must be of a class that has a bar() method which returns something; and that returned value shall be casted to X.

But you want to cast foo to X, because bar() exists on X, not on foo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the Operator Precedence in Java:
in case `(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context.close();` it will first perform `contecxt.close()` and then will try to cast the result of it to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. This is illegal casting as close() method does not return anything. 
With `((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();` you are telling to first cast context to type ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and then perform close() on the result.

See the relevant link [here](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) or [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)